# Weapons exporting process of the U.S?

Tags: united-states, president, congress

The US president Donald Trump [posted a tweet yesterdays](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/905047095488516098) which reads as follows:

> I am allowing Japan & South Korea to buy a substantially increased amount of highly sophisticated military equipment from the United States.

Does the President need approval from congress to export sophisticated weapons (potentially even B2 or F22 planes) to foreign countries?

Answer (score 5):

[It appears that the President can *propose* military exports, but *approval* is up to congress](http://www.dsca.mil/resources/arms-sales-congressional-review-process) if the dollar amount is above a certain number (not idea what 14 million buys, but it actually seems rather low in the context of 'sophisticated weaponry'):

> Under Section 36(b) of the Arms Export Control Act (AECA), Congress must be formally notified 30 calendar days before the Administration can take the final steps to conclude a government-to-government foreign military sale of:
>
> - major defense equipment valued at $14 million or more,
> - defense articles or services valued at $50 million or more,
> - or design and construction services valued at $200 million or more

Comment: How about ,,,,if the congress doesn't approve, what happens? The president can't sell the weapons?

Comment: @jinwoolee in terms of the law, so it seems. Though the law hasn't stopped presidents in the past (see: iran-contra scandal)

Comment: This is off a bit. The requirement to _formally notify_ Congress doesn't mean that the President has to have the _approval_ of Congress. The section does allow Congress to issue a joint resolution _banning_ the sale if they so desire, but it does not require them to explicitly approve it. Any such ban must occur within 30 days for most countries or within 15 days for NATO countries, Japan, Australia, South Korea, Israel, or New Zealand. If the President determines that an emergency exists which necessitates the sale, Congress' review process may not ban it.

Comment: @reirab I guess it's a tacit approval?

Comment: [See the paragraph at the end of 22 USC 2776(b)(1) for more information.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/22/2776#b_1_p) Or all of 22 USC 2776 if you're interested in all of the minutiae.

Comment: @blip Sort of, I guess. Requiring an act of Congress to stop something is quite a different standard from requiring one to allow it, though, especially if it can be filibustered in the Senate. And, if the President declares the situation to be an 'emergency,' then the sale goes through anyway.